# Return only JSON from PHP backend

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter

Hi guys i'm using Angular 4 for my front end to return json from backend but instead of pure json data it return me more, how can i return only json? Is the problem in the backend or should i do something in the front end?

I'm using codeigniter in the backend this inside the method:

```
$this->FAM->list_app();
```

from the model this already implementing `json_encode()`

and from the model backend:

```
$arrayindex=array();

foreach($query->result_array() as $r){
    $arrayindex[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($arrayindex);
```

[image]

Comment: show your php code

Comment: `<observable>.map(res => res.json())`

Comment: 9 times out of 10, your php code will echo a php array as in `json_encode($phpArr);`

Comment: You have to return the result as json encoded..`json_encode($array)`..Show Your php  code..After that only we can give the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on the frontEnd service by using **`res.json()`** and then access the **`body`** of it,

```
   yourService(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get('url')
        .map(this.success)
        .catch(this.fail);
    }

    private success(res: Response) {
        if (!res || res.status !== 200) {
            return [];
        }
        const data = res.json();
        const results = data ? (data.message ? data.message : []) : [];
        //return results;
          return data;
    }

    private fail(error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

Comment: since your response does not have body, just do data

Comment: LOL , @Sajeetharan

Comment: Continue; , I am deleting my answer.

Comment: actually i did change the return to data and when i console the data it already returning json format

Comment: @VivekDoshi no problem in posting new answer, what i mentioned was not to copy and paste with the same variable

Comment: No issue man, got your point. we'll meet soon in next questions :)

Comment: i will use the return object from data for my ngFor but this error return instead, what seems to be the problem here?



ProductComponent.html:15 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: can you post console.log of your result

Comment: this is the result of data:

(7) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: and your HTML looks like?

Comment: sorry man, my bad i just forgot something, that's why it returns and error everything is okay now. Thanks guys for the help

Comment: @Sajeetharan i updated your answer, the return data work form instead of results